# Referencing multiple (different) Div Id's using document.getElementById

Tags: javascript

I'm using script editor WP to create a Full screen overlay navigation feature.

I got the code from https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_fullscreen_overlay.asp.

I modified it some because I want to have multiple items to click in order to activate the feature. See pic below:

[image]

It works fine, except, no matter which one I click on, they both show the links associated with TTP. I want to click on Doctrine and see the Doctrine links, and click on TTP to see the TTP links.

I know this subject has been beat to death, but I cannot find anything that satisfies my requirement. Below is how I am referencing `getElementById`.

**Note:** I replaced my actual links with dummy links.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
    height: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(28,65,104, 0.9);
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #eccb13;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #800000;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay {overflow-y: auto;}
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="doctrineNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">Car</a>
    <a href="#">Bicycle</a>
    <a href="#">Boat</a>
    <a href="#">Airplane</a>
  </div>

</div>

<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9758; Doctrine</span>

<p></p>

<div id="ttpNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">Apple</a>
    <a href="#">Orange</a>
    <a href="#">Dog</a>
    <a href="#">Cat</a>
  </div>

</div>

<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9758; TTP</span>

<script>
function openNav() {
   document.getElementById("doctrineNav").style.height = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
   document.getElementById("doctrineNav").style.height = "0%";
}

function openNav() {
   document.getElementById("ttpNav").style.height = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
   document.getElementById("ttpNav").style.height = "0%";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If I change the script around like below, then no matter which one I click on, they both overlay on top of each other. In other words, I can see the TTP links, but also see the Doctrine links behind it.

```
<script>
function openNav() {
   document.getElementById("doctrineNav").style.height = "100%";
   document.getElementById("ttpNav").style.height = "100%";
}

function closeNav() {
   document.getElementById("doctrineNav").style.height = "0%";
   document.getElementById("ttpNav").style.height = "0%";
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51901445/reference-multiple-different-div-ids-using-document-getelementbyid

Below is the new code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
body {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
    height: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(28,65,104, 0.9);
    overflow-y: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.overlay a {
    padding: 8px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 36px;
    color: #eccb13;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.overlay a:hover, .overlay a:focus {
    color: #800000;
}

.overlay .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    right: 45px;
    font-size: 60px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .overlay {overflow-y: auto;}
  .overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="doctrineNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeDoctrine()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">Car</a>
    <a href="#">Bicycle</a>
    <a href="#">Boat</a>
    <a href="#">Airplane</a>
  </div>
</div>

<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openDoctrine()">&#9758; Doctrine</span>

<p></p>

<div id="ttpNav" class="overlay">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeTTP()">&times;</a>
  <div class="overlay-content">
    <a href="#">Apple</a>
    <a href="#">Orange</a>
    <a href="#">Dog</a>
    <a href="#">Cat</a> 
  </div>
</div>

<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openTTP()">&#9758; TTP</span>

<script>
function openDoctrine() {
   document.getElementById("doctrineNav").style.height = "100%";
}

function closeDoctrine() {
   document.getElementById("doctrineNav").style.height = "0%";
}

function openTTP() {
   document.getElementById("ttpNav").style.height = "100%";
}

function closeTTP() {
   document.getElementById("ttpNav").style.height = "0%";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```